# Why jquery mobile side panel touch sliding doesn't work smoothly without using event.preventDefault() on touch events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using event.preventDefault() on touchmove event to working panel slide properly. But it stops all scrolling in my app.

Without this code I am not able to open side panel smoothly. (It opens after 3-4 attempts)

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

});
```

Code to open/close panel on right swipe by finger

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(event){

      // Bind the swipeHandler callback function to the swipe event on div.box

      $( "[data-role='page']" ).on( "swiperight", function( event, ui ) {swipeRightHandler($.mobile.activePage.attr('id'));} );


        function swipeRightHandler( page_id ){
              $( "#"+page_id+"_panel" ).panel( "open" );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Used already, facing same issue, panel opens after sliding 3-4 times on screen.

Comment: Why do _you_ think it stops all scrolling? What do you think is the default action that you are preventing by calling `.preventDefault()` on touch move events at the `document` level?

Comment: `preventDefault` does what you're describing. You are using the wrong code to fix your problem. Your question should include the problem you're actually facing, not about a hack you're using that doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: @nnnnnn- yes, it stops all scrolling in my app.

Comment: So what is your question? Why do you call `preventDefault()` if you know that the default action being prevented is scrolling?

Comment: @nnnnnn- The question is, my apps panel touch sliding doesn't work smoothly without using preventDefault() or return false. But if I use any of these then scrolling doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried binding your event handler to the panel in question rather than to the whole document?

Comment: problem persist with binding event handler to panel

Comment: you can try a scrolling library to scroll http://iscrolljs.com/
This avoids all headaches with touch widgets preventing default scrolling action.